# Booting Linux from external HD connected to USB port on a Mac Mini

Tags: 12.04, mac

I have an external disk (usb) with Ubuntu Linux 12.04. I connect it to any of my Windows pcs to run Linux when necessary (modifying the BIOS to boot from the usb drive). I recently acquired a Mac Mini. I wonder if I could do the same thing, meaning, selecting the external drive where the Linux OS is located from the Start Up Manager in the Mac, and booting from it. Anybody here has experience doing what I'm considering? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can boot it off a usb drive.

Restart your Mac and press alt/option key while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick.

Reference: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: It is not a usb stick. It is an external hard disk that I connect to the pc via a usb port. They are different files systems, so that's why I want to know the way to do this.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but does this work with USB Hard Drives, not just sticks?

Answer (score 0):

You can enter boot menu by keeping "alt" key pressed upon startup. Unfortunately I am afraid that you won't be able to boot off the regular installation without extra steps like installing an EFI compatible grub first.